# custom login in yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

I am new to Yii 2.0 framework,I went through many articles on how a user can login using credentials from database and not in an array, but couldn't understand how it works, Every time I execute I get errors.

Comment: please, provide some code that you are trying to run, with more detailed explanation about what is going wrong

Comment: thank you for replying, i got the solution on stack overflow itself, now i am able to login using the credentials from the database table and not from an array, thank you stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yii Framework 2.0 Login With User Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790543/yii-framework-2-0-login-with-user-database) , This link about custom login in Yii 2.0 framework solved my above question :)