# Yii2 custom login is not working

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new in yii2, Right now i am working with custom login, i did all code for login but when i go in home page through index action i didn't get any session there, Here is my code

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if ($session->isActive) {
            echo 'sdsd'; die;
        }
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $model = new User();
        //if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $userName = $_POST['User']['UserName'];
            $password = $_POST['User']['Password'];
            $condition = "UserName = '".$userName."' AND Password = '".md5($password)."' AND Status = '1' AND UserType = '1' ";
            $loginData = User::find()->where($condition)->all();
            if(count($loginData)>0) {
                $username = $loginData[0]->UserName;
                $userID = $loginData[0]->UserID;
                $session = Yii::$app->session;
                $session->set('userName',$username);
                $session->set('userID',$userID);
                $this->redirect('index');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Username or password is incorrect');
            }
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Even after login it still consider me as guaest user, `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` what changes i need to do now ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii Framework 2.0 Login With User Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790543/yii-framework-2-0-login-with-user-database)

Comment: A couple of things. 1) [Don't use MD5 for passwords](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/52463/52211). 2) Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection since you are passing in user input directly into your condition. 3) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25828984/428543

Answer (score 1):

You don't login the user in Yii App

You don't need set the session you must assign the proper value to this function

```
return \Yii::$app->getUser()->login($yourUser, $yourRememberMe ? $this->module->rememberFor : 0);
```

see this [doc for user](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html)  and this for [login](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login%28%29-detail)

Comment: I know but i have different password method, so i can't use default login of yii2

Comment: You must however use the \Yii::$app->getUser()->login(..) or equivalent. Setting the session in invalid