# Connect Yii2 Login form to DB

Tags: database, authentication, yii2

I just installed Yii2 Basic and want to map the pre-existing login form to db. How can I do this? I have a db ready as well changed the db connection settings. What changes do I need to do in the model? This is my exiting Login Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

This is my User Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;

    private static $users = [
        '100' => [
            'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',
        ],
        '101' => [
            'id' => '101',
            'username' => 'demo',
            'password' => 'demo',
            'authKey' => 'test101key',
            'accessToken' => '101-token',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

How do I change this to achieve login connection from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change in `User.php` model (mainly three methods `findIdentity`, `findByUsername`, `validatePassword`). Below link will surely help you to go through this.
[Link 1](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/yii-2-user-login-from-database/), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790543/yii-framework-2-0-login-with-user-database) and [Link 3](https://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/change-the-default-authentication-from-text-to-database-in-yii/)

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use app\models\Users; // generated using Gii; user master table in db

class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;    

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        $user = Users::findOne(['id'=>$id]);
        if(!$user)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            $user_info = 
                [
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'username' => $user->username,
                    'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                    'email' => $user->email,                                
                    'image'=>$user->image,                
                    // assign other attributes too if needed
                ];
            return new static($user_info);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = Users::findOne(['id'=>$id]);
        if(!$user)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            $user_info = 
                [
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'username' => $user->username,
                    'first_name' => $user->first_name,
                    'last_name' => $user->last_name,
                    'email' => $user->email,                                
                    'image'=>$user->image,                
                    // assign other attributes, too if needed
                ];
            return new static($user_info);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password; // apply any encryption algo here to $password, if you have used any
    }

    // ...
    // ... other functions here
}
```